# Create JSON object dynamically via Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

I want the data in this serialize form I am looking the many of the examples but not worked properly. My code is here-

```
<select class="awe-select" name="rooms" id="rooms">                                         
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
<button class="awe-btn-default submit" type="submit">BOOK </button>

   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rooms").change(function() {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        $("#textboxDiv").html('');
        if(selVal > 0) {
            for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
                $("#textboxDiv").append("<div class='check_availability_group'><span class='label-group'>ROOM </span><div class='check_availability-field_group'><div class='check_availability-field'><label>Adult</label><select name='adult' id='adult' class='form-control activeInput' required><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></div><div class='check_availability-field'><label>Children</label><select class='form-control activeInput' id='children' name='children' required><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option  value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></div></div></div>");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

json code is here-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
    var array = [];
$("select[class=activeInput]").each(function() {
    array.push({
        adult: $(this).val(),
        children: $(this).val()
    });
});
});
});
// then to get the JSON string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
console.log(jsonString)
}
</script>
```

I want adult and child data as according to the room in this format like-

```
 "rooms": [
           {                       
          "children": 0,
           "adults": 1
           },
           {
            "children": 1,
             "adults": 2,                       
            }
         ]
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML, Bcoz I cannot see submit class in HTML.

Comment: @Mangesh- <button class="awe-btn-default submit" type="submit">BOOK </button>

Comment: Can you provide more information still most of the code is missing. textboxDiv etc

Comment: textboxDiv id code is in appended data.

Comment: Can you try to replace $("select[class=activeInput]") with $(".activeInput")
and move  this var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
console.log(jsonString) inside submit click.

refer:
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/5986mpxd/13/

Not a perfect answer but it will help you out.

Comment: This code will work, but return repeated when I select only one room and give the value adult":"2" and "children":"1" then got this input- [{"adult":"2","children":"2"}, {"adult":"1","children":"1"}] instead of this- [{"adult":"2","children":"1"}]

Comment: This will definitely work now. https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/5986mpxd/22/ Updated the Condition. array.push({ ...($(this).attr("name") === "adult" &&{adult: $(this).val()}), ...($(this).attr("name") === "children" && {children: $(this).val()}) });

Comment: this will make separate curly braces like- [{"adult":"1"},{"children":"2"}] intead of- [{"adult":"1","children":"2"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the link below :
https://jsfiddle.net/ulric_469/5986mpxd/31/

```
<select class="awe-select" name="rooms" id="rooms">                                         
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
 <div class= "temp" id ="textboxDiv">

 </div>
 <button class="awe-btn-default submit" type="submit">BOOK </button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rooms").change(function() {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        $("#textboxDiv").html("");
        if(selVal > 0) {
            for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
                $("#textboxDiv").append("<div class='check_availability_group'><span class='label-group'>ROOM </span><div class='check_availability-field_group'><div class='check_availability-field'><label>Adult</label><select name='adult' id='adult' class='form-control activeInput' required><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></div><div class='check_availability-field'><label>Children</label><select class='form-control activeInput' id='children' name='children' required><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option  value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select></div></div></div>");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".submit").click(function() {
    var array = [];     
$(".check_availability-field_group").each(function() {
    array.push({
        adult: +$(this).find("select[name= 'adult']").val(),
        children: +$(this).find("select[name= 'children']").val()
    });
});
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array);
    console.log(jsonString)
});

});
```

Comment: How  i get the value of adult and children as a integer type ? Like-[{ "adult"=1,"children"=2 }] in an array. I am not want value as a- [{ "adult"="1","children"="2 "}]